# merge partial matched strings

Tags: r, perl, pattern-matching

I am struggling with trying to combine partially matched strings from two files.

File 1 contains a list of unique strings. These strings are partially matched to a number of strings in File 2. How do I merge the rows in file 1 with file 2 for every  matched case

File1

```
mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660
```

File2

```
mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGA
mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
mmu-miR-677-5p_TTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTAC
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTACC
```

Desired output

```
mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239     mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGA
mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239     mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239     mmu-miR-677-5p_TTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660  mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTAC
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660  mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTACC
```

I have tried using `pmatch()` in R, but don't get it right. I looks like something perl would handle??

Maybe something like this:

```
perl -ne'exec q;perl;, "-ne", q $print (/\Q$.$1.q;/?"$. YES":$. .q\; NO\;);, "file2" if m;^(.*)_pat1;' file1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a brief Perl solution, which saves all the data from `file1` in a hash and then retrieves it as `file2` is scanned

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @files = qw/ file1.txt file2.txt /;

my %file1 = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $files[0];
  map /([^_]+)_(\S+)/, <$fh>;
};

open my $fh, '<', $files[1];
while (<$fh>) {
  my ($key) = /([^_]+)/;
  printf "%-32s%s", "${key}_$file1{$key}", $_;
}
```

**output**

```
mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239     mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGA
mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239     mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239     mmu-miR-677-5p_TTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660  mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTAC
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660  mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTACC
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course you may do it in R. Indeed, `pmatch`ing whole strings won't give you the desired result - you've got to match appropriate substrings.

I assume that in file 1 the first identifier is 677 and not 667, otherwise it's hard to guess the matching scheme (I assume your example is only a part of a bigger database).

```
file1 <- readLines(textConnection('mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660'))

file2 <- readLines(textConnection('mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGA
mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
mmu-miR-677-5p_TTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTAC
mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTACC'))

library(stringi)
file1_id <- stri_extract_first_regex(file1, "^.*?(?=_)")
file2_id <- stri_extract_first_regex(file2, "^.*?(?=_)")

cbind(file1=file1[match(file2_id, file1_id)], file2=file2)
##      file1                            file2                                     
## [1,] "mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239"    "mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGA"  
## [2,] "mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239"    "mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT"
## [3,] "mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239"    "mmu-miR-677-5p_TTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT" 
## [4,] "mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660" "mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTAC" 
## [5,] "mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660" "mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTACC"
```

Comment: when i read from my csv file it complains about str not being a character vector:     Error in stri_extract_first_regex(file1, "^.*?(?=_)") : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)

Comment: @user3741035 you should at least try to read files before matching them. The answers here assumes that you have the basic to read/write R files.

Comment: @user3741035: Indeed, here I assume that `file1` and `file2` is a character vector - each string is a single `mmu-miR-...` If it's a list, then call `unlist`, for example. If it was read with `read.csv`, use `objectname$columnname`.

Comment: Got it to work using a for loop for readLines: Is there a better way:     fileName="mature_seq_merge.csv"
conn=file(fileName,open="r")
file1=readLines(conn)
for (i in 1:length(linn)){
  print(linn[i])
}
close(conn)

Answer (score 2):

You can `agrep` for fuzzy search. You should play with distance. Here I am fixing it manually to 11.

Basically I am doing this to extract lines number that matches each word in file1:

```
sapply(file1,agrep,file2,max=11)
$`mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239`
[1] 1 2 3

$`mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660`
[1] 4 5
```

To get the result of a data.frame:

```
do.call(rbind,
     lapply(file1,
       function(x)
        data.frame(file1=x,
                   file2=agrep(x,file2,max=11,value=T))))


                         file1                                    file2
1    mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239   mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGA
2    mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239 mmu-miR-677-5p_CTTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
3    mmu-miR-677-5p_MIMAT0017239  mmu-miR-677-5p_TTCAGTGATGATTAGCTTCTGACT
4 mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660  mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTAC
5 mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_MIMAT0000660 mmu-miR-181a-1-3p_ACCATCGACCGTTGATTGTACC
```

Comment: It complains about differing number of rows in my imput files: 'Warning message:
In agrep(x, file2, max = 11, value = T) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Error in do.call(rbind, lapply(file1, function(x) data.frame(file1 = x,  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'args' in selecting a method for function 'do.call': Error in data.frame(file1 = x, file2 = agrep(x, file2, max = 11, value = T)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1908, 0'

Comment: @user3741035 what did you get when you try with data `file1` and `file2` provided in gagolews answer?